# How to install multiple fonts at once?

Tags: fonts

How can I install multiple fonts (like 40-50) at once? Do I have to do it manually or is there any option to add them once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install them for all users, you need root access.

I'm going to assume the fonts are saved in your Downloads folder, in another folder called "fonts".

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/fonts/* /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

Then a restart and you should have your font.

Comment: You shouldn't modify stuff under `/usr` outside `/usr/local`, that conflicts with the package manager. Doesn't `/usr/local/share/fonts` work (I don't have elementary around to make sure)? And do you actually need to restart your session to use the new fonts?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.font` folder in home if it doesn't exists and copy all your fonts on the `.font` folder.

Comment: These will only be available to the current user. A perfect answer would list install options for both the current user, and the whole system, as well as listing the downsides of installing too many fonts.